# When trying to optimise my classifier models using grid search cross validation, my f1 score decreases to 0

Tags: python, classification

I have run RandomForestClassifier and MLPClassifier models and I am receiving a respective accuracy and f1 score of 83% & 39% vs 86% & 34%.

My data set is imbalanced with 523 in one class and 91 in another class, it has 22 features.
When I try to optimise my models using grid search cross validation, my accuracy slightly increases for both models but my f1 score decreases to 0%, what could be the reason(s) for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without taking a look at your code (please consider editing you question). The 83-86% accuracy is very suspicious since a naive classifier which always predicts the overrepresented class would achieve 86% accuracy on your dataset.

Also, take a look at precision and recall since these have to be 0 when the F1 score is zero.

[image: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall]

The reason could be that during cross-validation there are data splits with no or very few labels from the underrepresented class and the particular model does not learn to distinguish between them. In this case the accuracy could seem reasonable but the f1 score would be zero when the "true" (=1) class is the underrepresented.